# How do I center the text within in LazyHorizontalGrid

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Currently the text is justified to the start, but I'm wanting the text justified to the center

Here's my code

```
                LazyHorizontalGrid(
                    rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .padding(top = 55.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(
                        otherFacilities,
                    ) { index, item ->
                            Text(
                                "${item.displayName}",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .wrapContentSize()
                                    .clickable { selectedFacility = item }
                                    .background(color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(18.dp))
                                    .padding(5.dp)
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                    }
                }
```

The end result should be that Dental is centered

[image]

Comment: Have you tried surrounding your LazyHorizontalGrid inside a Box which has contentAlignment = Alignment.Center?

Comment: Let me try that, my immediate thought is wouldn't that just center the grid and not the text?

Comment: Is there any difference if you remove the `.wrapContentSize()` Modifier from the `Text` Composable?

Comment: @BenjyTec no change